# Java Array split: Quick way to split a list of indices of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have Topic1000Url class

```
public class Topic1000Url {

     private int [] url_id;
     private double [] sum_url_Tsim;    
}
```

The problem is I want to make a split func can split the 2 arrays.

Comment: @Pshemo, You've edited it but it's still not clear what exactly the problem is. Are these two arrays in some way related? Should they be split based on some common criteria? I have no idea how to answer this question!

Comment: @JamieReid My edit wasn't meant to clarify OP request, but to correct format of code example. My comment also was meant to inform OP that this question is not clear enough. So if you have any additional questions you should ask them to Rehama.

Comment: @pshemo, aha I thought you knew something we all didn't,  apologies! So I guess my questions above still stand. Please help us help you and answer my questions.

Comment: @Rehama Since you doesn't seem like regular Stack Overflow participant you probably don't know that to add more informations you can use [[edit]] option placed below your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void split(TopicLinkdata source_sim_arr,
        TopicLinkdata trainingSet_sim_arr, TopicLinkdata testData_sim_arr)
{
    trainingSet_sim_arr.setUrl_id(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            source_sim_arr.getUrl_id(), 0,
            source_sim_arr.getUrl_id().length / 2));
    testData_sim_arr.setUrl_id(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            source_sim_arr.getUrl_id(),
            source_sim_arr.getUrl_id().length / 2,
            source_sim_arr.getUrl_id().length));

    trainingSet_sim_arr.setSum_url_Tsim(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            source_sim_arr.getSum_url_Tsim(), 0,
            source_sim_arr.getSum_url_Tsim().length / 2));
    testData_sim_arr.setSum_url_Tsim(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            source_sim_arr.getSum_url_Tsim(),
            source_sim_arr.getSum_url_Tsim().length / 2,
            source_sim_arr.getSum_url_Tsim().length));
}
```